# Ordenar campos de um GRID em ordem alfabética - Delphi

Tags: delphi, grid, devexpress, order, dbgrid

Preciso ordenar os campos do grid do meu gráfico em ordem alfabética (Uso `Delphi 10.1 Berlim` e o componente `TcxDBPivotGrid` da DevExpress),

Segue imagem em anexo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OBS -> Preciso ordenar os campos que estão na Grid do retângulo vermelho.
 Eles podem ser arrastados pelo usuário para o retângulo amarelo, porém quando o usuário devolver o campo do retângulo amarelo para o retângulo vermelho, a ordenação deve ocorrer de forma automática.

Alguém tem uma ideia de como posso fazer isto?

Comment: Da uma olhada se este link não te ajuda: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E331/customfieldsort-how-to-sort-field-values-by-invisible-data-column-values

Comment: Já tentou colocar a rotina de ordenação no evento tipo `OnDragDrop`. 
O `OnDragDrop` ocorre quando o usuário solta um objeto que está sendo arrastado.